# Django Rosetta - translate by user permission rather than "translators" group

Tags: django, translation, django-authentication, django-rosetta

How can I enable users to perform **django-rosetta** translations without assign each user in turn to the new `translators` auth group?

I currently have users associated to specific auth groups depending on their website role. I would like to assign a new auth permission, like: `sites|sites|Can Translate` and add this to an existing role. This will keep the minimal User administration so that users with the role of `Gatekeeper` will be assigned the the `Gatekeeper` auth group alone, and be able to translate.

Is this possible without hacking django-rosetta?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `rosetta` has a `ROSETTA_ACCESS_CONTROL_FUNCTION` setting that makes possible to customize access permissions.

> An alternative function that determines if a given user can access the translation views. This function receives a user as its argument, and returns a boolean specifying whether the passed user is allowed to use Rosetta or not.

I hope it helps